# Class inheritance using Class instances instead of Classes

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

What is the proper way of inheriting attributes from class instances in Python 3?

For example how to inherit attributes such as `lastname` from an instance of the `Family` class:

```
class Family:
    def __init__(self, last):
        self.lastname = last

class Person(Family):
    def __init__(self, first):
        self.firstname = first

# The below code does not work an is an example of the desired usage:
family = Family('Smith')
person = Person('David', family)
```

The objective is for `person` to inherit attributes such as `lastname` from the `family` instance of the `Family` class:

```
>>> person.firstname
'David'
>>> person.lastname
'Smith'
```

Comment: You would not inherit these attributes, you would need to initialize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options: implement `def lastname(self)` for the person class and defer the implementation to the stored family.

Alternatively, you could implement `__getattr__` on the person and forward everything to the family. I'm not yet sure about this approach though, it seems too similar to regular inheritance. E.g. if family had a method `number_of_members(self)`, each person would also have it. If that is okay, regular inheritance works just as well.

Comment: another thought: You could use a decorator on each method of `Family` that you would like to copy to `Person`. Then in `Person.__init__` you assign all the methods with the correct decorator. Or just check for the decorator in `__getattr__`.

Comment: Regular inheritance works on Classes but not Class instance though doesn't it? I don't mind if the methods of family are inherited, it's the attributes of the instances that are needed. 

Another answer suggests to assign the attributes manually. There are tens of attributes which need to be inherited though. Is there a way to inherit the attributes from the class instance without assigning them explicitly?


Or am I doing it wrong and should `People` instances be added to the `Family` class instance?

Comment: @dave: You're right, so what you want is to proxy method calls. Have a look at `__getattr__`. You shoud be able to write something along of this: `def __getattr__(self, name): return getattr(self.family, name)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need something like:

```
class Family:
    def __init__(self, last):
        self.lastname = last

class Person(Family):
    def __init__(self, first, family):
        self.firstname = first
        if isinstance(family, Family):
            family = family.lastname
        self.lastname = family

family = Family('Smith')
person = Person('David', family)
```

or maybe:

```
class Person(Family):
    def __init__(self, first, family):
        self.firstname = first
        if isinstance(family, Family):
            family = family.lastname
        super().__init__(family)
```

Comment: Is there a way to inherit from `family` without specifying `self.family = family.lastname`? What if family has 100 attributes which need to be inherited? Is there a way to just inherit them without assigning them explicitly?

Comment: Not that that I am aware without some tricks.  Let's see what someone else comes up with.  One way, if you have a lot of attributes, is to keep the attribute list as a list, and use `**kwargs` to init the classes.  But this still requires explicit code to do the initing of one instance from another.